# ASP.Net MVC regex for multi-line string

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need to only allow following characters in multi-line textarea input field:

space, numbers, English letters and following special characters: ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ ` [ \ ~ ] ^ _ { | }

I figured it out except the multi-line part:

```
        [RegularExpression("^[ -~]+$", ErrorMessage = @"Allowed characters for item description: space, numbers, English letters and following special characters: ! "" # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ ` [ \ ~ ] ^ _ {{ | }}")]
```

It works as desired as long as everything is entered as a single line. I just can't figure out how to extend it to multi-line.

Comment: Does the tested value contain more than one line?

Comment: Try `"^[ -~]+(?:\r?\n[ -~]+)*$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: this is almost it. It works except if the very first or the very last line is an empty line

Comment: @JoeSchmoe What does that mean? That lines me be empty? Then use `"^[ -~]*(?:\r?\n[ -~]*)*$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: your second version seems to be working 100%. What I meant before: if I enter "ABC[Enter]DEF[Enter]" then it would not valdiate but now it does. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"^[ -~]*(?:\r?\n[ -~]*)*$"
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[ -~]*` - 0 or more printable ASCII chars
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching

  - `\r?\n` - an optional (1 or 0) CR symbols and then an LF symbol (so that it matches Windows and Unix/Linux line endings)
  - `[ -~]*` - 0 or more printable ASCII chars
- `)*` - ... zero or more times
- `$` - end of string.